# Fighting Metal Gear without enough plastic explosives, what now?

Tags: metal-gear

I'm replaying the first Metal Gear game via the Metal Gear Solid HD Collection on the PS Vita, and have now reached Metal Gear itself.

Unfortunately, I messed up and went to challenge that tank with only 13 plastic explosives instead of 16. Without enough explosives, I can't beat the boss, and I can't go back either, as the door behind me is shut and doesn't open at all.

Also, when I die, I'm back at the beginning of the fight, so there's no way I can return to fetch more explosives.

What can I do? Is reloading a save file from before I even reached Building 3 really the only option I have left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die many times and you will receive full ammo

Comment: Technically, yes, it is a solution. He is proposing that the OP dies many times in sequence so that they'll receive all their ammo back and thus have enough plastic explosives to destroy Metal Gear. I haven't played MG1, so I don't know if that actually works, however.

Comment: I'm not sure how many times I died exactly, but this answer is correct. After dying 5 or more times, I heard a chime and now I have 40 explosives instead of 13.